# pandoc: convert HTML table to DOCX

Tags: pandoc

I have a very simplistic HTML document with a table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Analysis</title>
</head>
<body>
<TABLE border=1>
<TR> <TD> 18.365                </TD> <TD> 1     </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD> 23.465                </TD> <TD> 1     </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD> 26.020                </TD> <TD> 1     </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD> 14.371                </TD> <TD> 1     </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD> 17.258                </TD> <TD> 1     </TD> </TR>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

and I would like to create a DOCX file from it using pandoc. In the result, however, the table is completely messed up. Can anyone please help me with a working example? It is the last step in a complex workflow I have and I assume that a table should be possible.

Pandoc version:1.12.4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a regression that has already been fixed in the development version
(https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1341).  You can install the development
version from source or revert to a package for 1.12.3.3.  This will be fixed in the next pandoc release.

Comment: Thanks, it works. For reference, I followed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wting/8498731) to install cabal and then used `cabal install --global --force-reinstalls pandoc-1.12.3.3`